# Django - Running tests multiple times with different fixtures

Tags: django, nose, django-nose

Is there way to run tests multiple times with different fixtures with django-nose (or any other library)? I want to check how my project runs with different number of data. As I searched I find out that there is no way to pass fixtures as argument to manage.py test.

Best regards

Comment: Can you not write into the test what you want it to do?..

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible with manage.py test. But as you said I had to create my own script to run such tests cause I couldn't find any simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your preferred fixture before each test. [See the Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture)